# Dev mode in Angular 6 and NodeJS Express server

Tags: angular, express, webpack, server

I'm trying to run in the dev mode one application which is build on top of Angular-Universal-Starter pack.

The idea is that there is a NodeJS Express server - for the API and Angular 6 for the front-end.

My Angular package.json file contains following:

```
   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve && node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run 
   webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run angular.io- 
   example:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress -- 
   colors"
  },
```

When I'm trying to do : node server.js, I'm getting an error :

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

In the end of the server.js I have:

```
// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  require("./server/data/insertData")(db);
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

But I never get this message (node server listening...) and that's strange.

Is it possible somehow to start node server and to target it with the Postman?
I really tried all the commands...

Comment: Actually - my biggest problem - I can't understand how to launch back end to work with it. For the Angular - ok, I can do "ng serve", but back, as it is linked with the webpack - have no idea how to start

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs uses [require](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) syntax not [ES6 import](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) because its not compiled by babel like angular is.

So you should use:

```
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node.js');
```

Or if you want to try the [nodejs exprimental modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), start the script like this:

```
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
```

Comment: gives the same error if I try with experimental modules param